# wifi unavailable(wireless) on acer aspire 4750z

Tags: networking

```
mizisport@Mizi64-Aspire-4750:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for mizisport: 
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01


mizisport@Mizi64-Aspire-4750:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for mizisport: 
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 20:7c:8f:71:39:0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.18.0-18-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:90500000-9050ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0f0
       version: 10
       serial: 20:6a:8a:4c:bb:d6
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=sb ip=192.168.1.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:90400000-9040ffff memory:90410000-9041ffff memory:7f200000-7f2007ff
       serial: 20:7c:8f:71:39:0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.18.0-18-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:90500000-9050ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0f0
       version: 10
       serial: 20:6a:8a:4c:bb:d6
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=sb ip=192.168.1.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:90400000-9040ffff memory:90410000-9041ffff memory:7f200000-7f2007ff
mizisport@Mizi64-Aspire-4750:~$
```

```
mizisport@Mizi64-Aspire-4750:~$ rfkill list 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no 
4: hci0: Bluetooth 
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

mizisport@Mizi64-Aspire-4750:~$
```

Comment: Please add output of `rfkill list` to the question and check that wireless is enabled in BIOS and switched on by hardware switch on laptop.

Comment: mizisport@Mizi64-Aspire-4750:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
mizisport@Mizi64-Aspire-4750:~$

Answer (score 0):

According to [official Acer documentation](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/ID/content/support-product/3716;-;) you may need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to enable wireless:

> [image: wi-fi killswitch]

Comment: not working.... fn+f3 is for airplane mode..

Comment: Then try `sudo rfkill unblock all`.